# Phillips HUE SDK in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks, philips-hue

I am very new to Swift!  I do have some experience with Objective-C (although it has been around two years since i've really written anything in it).  I am trying to use the Phillips HUE SDK with Swift, and am having some trouble!  I am trying to re-write the following Objective-C code into Swift:

```
// Start search for bridges
[self.bridgeSearch startSearchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *bridgesFound) {
   //Search complete
   [self showBridgesFound:bridgesFound];
}
```

I have had no luck looking online for a solution on this, and there is no documentation through Phillips.  Has anyone had experience with this, could you please provide assistance?

Comment: Translating from ObjC to Swift is really easy. What have you got so far? You're probably almost there. Show your translation and let's fix it.

Comment: @matt I will have to get the exact code I attempted off of my work laptop on Monday.

Also, i'm not sure why this was down voted - seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call throwing some Objective-C code at the wall and asking SO to translate it into Swift for you "legitimate", no.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of SO to help fellow developers that have questions or issues?  Maybe this isn't a very complex question but for someone very new at swift and relatively inexperienced with Objective-C, should I have just sat in confusion?  I spent a good amount of time trying to find the solution online and learning about the problem but was stuck.

Comment: No one is suggesting you should just sit in confusion. Remember my first comment? "Translating from ObjC to Swift is really easy. What have you got so far? You're probably almost there. Show your translation and let's fix it." I was helping you to turn this into a great SO question, and then I would have been happy to help work with you to solve it. Since then your response has been to do nothing but complain and you still haven't posted your attempted translation.

Comment: I made one comment about the question being down voted, I also mentioned that I don't have the code in front of me and won't until Monday.  I do appreciate that you are willing to help work through the code with me, and I still plan on posting the code Monday.  I was just confused as to why this was originally down voted, but thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. It's a "wisdom of the crowd" site. You have to take the bitter with the sweet. But I've been here a while, so I do have a sense of what makes a good SO question, and of what the crowd might downvote for. The way your question was asked, it seemed just plain lazy: "I can't do this, please just write my code for me." That is not in the SO spirit. Showing your own attempt, and giving details as to what's going wrong, is at least an effort that will gain you some goodwill. Your question showed _no_ effort - and that's exactly what people downvote for.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm still new to SO and will definitely keep that tip in mind for future questions! Thanks

Comment: I had something like this (altered it a few times but couldn't get any of them to work obviously): bridgeSearch.startSearchWithCompletionHandler(bridgesFound: Dictionary)

Comment: That would be miles off. Even if there were a pure Dictionary type, this parameter needs to be typed as a _function_, not as a dictionary.

Comment: Could you briefly explain the meaning behind the answer given below (specifically `{ (bridgesFound: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in showBridgesFound(bridgesFound)`)  I sort of understand that it is calling the startSearch... function, and storing the data (i think) into the bridgesFound variable.  What I am unsure of is what `[NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in` represents

Comment: I already sort of answered that in my preceding comment. The parameter is a function (that takes a dictionary) - not a dictionary. If you need a longer explanation, please ask a new question (and blip me through a comment)! I'd love to explain this at length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tricky piece is figuring out the syntax of the Swift equivalent of the NSDictionary.

```
self.bridgeSearch.startSearchWithCompletionHandler { (bridgesFound: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    self.showBridgesFound(bridgesFound)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I will have to try this (when I get back to my work computer on Monday).  I had something very very similar but had errors, hopefully this is all i need - thank you :)

Comment: @5T4TiC: Do you have sample code for Philips HUE swift integration?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.bridgeSearch!.startSearch { (bridgesFound: [AnyHashable : Any]!) -> Void in
            //self.showBridgesFound(bridgesFound)
            print(bridgesFound)
        }
```

I think you need to use [AnyHashable : Any] in swift 3 as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013323/cannot-convert-anyhashable-in-swift-3).