# cannot convert AnyHashable in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, branch.io

I have following method, which written in swift (before swift 3). below is the method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification launchOptions: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void {
    Branch.getInstance().handlePushNotification(launchOptions)
}
```

it gives and error of `Use of undeclared type AnyHashable`. how can I covert this to swift 3. I tried with following.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Void {
        Branch.getInstance().handlePushNotification(launchOptions)
    }
```

it removes the error, but don't know it act like same way. hope your help with this. thanx in advance.

Comment: show your handlePushNotification code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**type conversion**

[image]

do like

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
print("received a notification")
   Branch.getInstance().handlePushNotification(launchOptions)

}
```

for more information you can get from [branch in Git](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking)